# Package Installation Failure

Tags: 10.10

Whenever I try to install any new package or upgrade a package, it fails with below mentioned error:

```
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-5ubuntu1) ...
/etc/environment: line 1: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked all the directories mentioned in PATH variable exists.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I am using 10.10.

Comment: The problem is not in the path names.  It is in the fact that something other than /bin/sh (tcsh maybe?) is interpreting /etc/environment.  Note the error message.  Do you have a non default SHELL variable set when running this?

Comment: My default SHELL variable is set to /bin/bash and i haven't modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg -r install-info
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```